# Make all HTML components disappear, only show the background image

Tags: jquery

I want to implement a fancy feature in my website. I have a nice background image in my website, and HTML components on top of it. I want to put a link somewhere in the background image such that, when a user clicks that link, all the HTML elements disappear, and the user can view the full image. This feature can be toggled. Can anyone suggest me how I may achieve this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a CSS class that hides all child elements:

```
.hideall * { display: none; }
```

Now you can add the class to the body to hide everything, and remove the class to show everything again:

```
$(function(){
  $('#hidelink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').addClass('hideall');
  });
  $('body')click(function(){
    $('body').removeClass('hideall');
  });
});
```

The advantage with this method is that it won't potentially mess up the layout by setting a `diplay` style on elements, and when showing the contents it won't make things visible that should remain hidden.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I make it a little fancy, and make my HTML elements disappear in some particular fashion, like fade away, or scatter away, etc.

Comment: @rookieRailer: The requires that the content is in elements that you can apply animation to. Basically you would put something like `class="hidecontainer"` on the containers in the page, then you could just use animation like `$('.hidecontainer').fadeOut()` and `$('.hidecontainer').fadeIn()` to hide and show them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should be able to adopt this easily, as my CSS is pretty well designed, in a hierarchical fashion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide everything pretty easily:

```
$('body > *').hide();
```

Although that'll also hide your toggle link. You probably want to put all of the hidable elements in a container (like a div) and toggle the visibility on that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.show_bg').click(function() {
    $('body > *').toggle();
    $(this).show();
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/Uk9MR/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap all the elements you want to toggle within a wrapper div except for the button you're using to toggle this functionality.

```
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>sdfsdf
        <!-- All your content -->
    </div>
    <button name='toggle_bg'>Toggle background image</button>
</body>
<script>
$("button[name='toggle_bg']").click(function(){
    $("div#wrapper").toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why use `<button name="toggle_bgg">` instead of `<button id="toggle_bg">`? The `name` attribute is only supposed to be used for form elements that hold values to be sent along with the a form submission. `id` is for styling and DOM-manipulation.

Comment: Either one would work but in this case, yes, id would probably be semantically correct.  I often use <button> within forms so I've gotten into the habit of selecting them by the name attribute.